# How can I fetch data from another website to my wordpress website with mysql database

Tags: plugins, php, functions, mysql

I can make wordpress website but I have an issue with this. I want to fetch data from another third party website to my own wordpress site with the mysql database.
I want to fetch only one table with the dynamic entries form the third party website.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a new connection from function:

```
$wpdb_b = new wpdb( "user", "password", "brian_db", "localhost" );
$wpdb_b->get_results( "SELECT * FROM brian_table" );
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You should have a remote mysql option in your cpanel to allow you to do that if not then you may ask your hosting provider for more assistance after that:

**Use the following configuration settings for connecting to your database:**

Host name = (use the server IP address)

Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)

Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)

Database password = (the password you entered for that database user)
MySQL Connection Port = 3306